# how to get total count of number of employees according to level

Tags: sql-server

I have a table - **userinfo** where i'm having some attributes **userid,FLname,ReportTo,TotalempUnderUser** i'm trying to find total number of employees in each level how can i achieve that

For **user** with **null**, **ReportTo** should have to get all user **count** in the table and child below it should have to get all the **ReportTo**, **count** further
and
here is the expected output

```
userid         FLname     ReportTo        TotalempUnderUser

1               abc         null            4
2               xyz         1               2
3               aaa         1               0
4               wer         2               1
5               dxd         4               0
```

i dont have any idea how to get this  and 
i have tried this query

```
With cte as (
  select userid,ReportTo from userinfo
  union all
  select c.userid,e.ReportTo 
  from cte c join userinfo e on (c.ReportTo=e.userid)
  )

select m.ReportTo,count(e.userid) as Count_of_Employees
from userinfo m 
left join cte e on (e.ReportTo=m.ReportTo) where m.userid=1
group by m.ReportTo
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

if i check for userid 1 for **TotalempUnderUser** the expected output to be **4**

Comment: can you make a SQL fiddle and provide the actual table data so i can try to solve your problem , your question is not clear

Comment: Is your DBMS mysql or sql-server?

Comment: Search for Common Table Expression(CTE) in SQL server and you will be able to solve it. You can do it yourself and also you can make use of subqueries.

Comment: @GauravChaudhary can you please explain with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really gave me a hard time, I hope there is a simpler statement (and I hope this is correct, at least with your sample it seems to be):

```
; with cte as (
    select userid, reportTo from userinfo a
        where not exists (select * from userinfo b where b.reportTo = a.userid)
    union all
    select ui.userid, ui.reportTo 
    from userinfo ui join cte on cte.reportTo = ui.userid 
    where ui.reportTo is not null
    union all
    select cte.userid, ui.reportTo from userinfo ui join cte on cte.reportTo = ui.userid
    where cte.reportTo is not null
    )
, managers as (
    select x.reportTo, count(*) TotalempUnderUser 
    from (select distinct userid, reportTo 
          from cte 
          where reportTo is not null) x 
    group by x.reportTo
)
select managers.reportTo as userid, managers.TotalempUnderUser 
from managers 
union all 
select userid, 0 
from userinfo ui left join managers on ui.userid = managers.reportTo 
where managers.reportTo is null
order by 1
;
```

Comment: you really made my day brother it works for data records of 20k i hope we can make if further more simpler and more effective and i really appreciate your help and thank you