# How to make union all containing query as scalar function in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create a scalar function where it contains **uinon all** of 3 queries but i'm not able to create here is my query

```
USE [dbname]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[userinfo_getcountofemplyoee1]    Script Date: 3/23/2017 11:51:22 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create FUNCTION [dbo].[userinfo_gettotalcountofemplyoee](@parm Nvarchar(50)) RETURNS INTEGER

AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @id INTEGER,@child nvarchar


   ;with cte as
(
   select userid, reportTo 
from userinfo a
where not exists (select * from userinfo b where b.reportTo = a.userid)

union all

select ui.userid, ui.reportTo 
from userinfo ui join cte on cte.reportTo = ui.userid 
where ui.reportTo is not null

union all

select cte.userid, ui.reportTo 
from userinfo ui join cte on cte.reportTo = ui.userid
where cte.reportTo is not null
)
, managers as (
select x.reportTo, count(*) TotalempUnderUser 
from (select distinct userid, reportTo 
      from cte 
      where reportTo is not null) x 
      group by x.reportTo)

      select managers.TotalempUnderUser 
from managers where  managers.reportTo=627

union all 

select  0 
from userinfo ui left join managers on ui.userid = managers.reportTo 
where managers.reportTo is null and userid=627

    select @id=TotalempUnderUser from cte

    return @id
END
```

but i'm getting the error

> Msg 444, Level 16, State 2, Procedure userinfo_getcountofemplyoee1, Line 9
>   Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.

i have updated the answer please check this now

my sample data is

```
userid         FLname     ReportTo        TotalempUnderUser

1               abc         null            4
2               xyz         1               2
3               aaa         1               0
4               wer         2               1
```

and the expected output is

```
TotalempUnderUser
4
```

Comment: Is your cte returns how many records?

Comment: Only one record **TotalempUnderUser**

Comment: ok wait...........

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
Declare @n int

;with cte as
(
    Your query here that returns TotalempUnderUser
)
select @n=column_name from cte

return @n
```

or it seems like yours

```
Declare @id integer

    ;with cte as
    (
        Your query here that returns TotalempUnderUser
    )
    select @id=column_name from cte

    return @id
```

Comment: Did you got what i mean here.. I'm just giving it shortly to make you understand too fast as i can.

Comment: Ok i'll try to help you build your query

Comment: build your query one by one.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data and an expected result here?

Comment: Wait for a while

Comment: Where is TotalempUnderUser = 4 came from? from number of users?

Comment: its actually the total no. employee under that employee with userid=1

Comment: then it is a very simple query where user_id = 1 why your example above is too long?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42918940/how-to-get-total-count-of-number-of-employees-according-to-level please check this question once i'm actually working on that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138811/discussion-between-suhas-and-reds).